# Error coming while upgrading cowboy to cowboy2

Tags: elixir, cowboy

I have elixir application which I am using with plug(no Phoenix), I was trying to upgrade it to cowboy2 from cowboy. I am using VS code for development, I keep getting following error when I am running server

```
    ** (Mix) Could not start application ok_api: exited in: 
OkApi.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :proplists.get_value/3
        (stdlib) proplists.erl:215: :proplists.get_value(:num_acceptors, %{max_connections: 16384, num_acceptors: 100, socket_opts: [port: 4001]}, 10)
        (ranch) /Users/ok/Documents/migration/ok_api/deps/ranch/src/ranch.erl:116: :ranch.child_spec/5
        (plug_cowboy) lib/plug/cowboy.ex:183: Plug.Cowboy.child_spec/1
        (ok_api) lib/ok_api.ex:92: OkApi.start/2
        (kernel) application_master.erl:277: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

*this is my children config*

```
children = [
 Plug.Cowboy.child_spec(scheme: :http, plug: OkApi.Router, options: [port: 4001])
 ]
```

these 2 version I have in my mix.lock file

```
"plug": {:hex, :plug, "1.7.1", "8516d565fb84a6a8b2ca722e74e2cd25ca0fc9d64f364ec9dbec09d33eb78ccd", [:mix], [{:mime, "~> 1.0", [hex: :mime, optional: false]}, {:plug_crypto, "~> 1.0", [hex: :plug_crypto, optional: false]}]},
"plug_cowboy": {:hex, :plug_cowboy, "2.0.1", "d798f8ee5acc86b7d42dbe4450b8b0dadf665ce588236eb0a751a132417a980e", [:mix], [{:cowboy, "~> 2.5", [hex: :cowboy, optional: false]}, {:plug, "~> 1.7", [hex: :plug, optional: false]}]},
```

app is getting compiled fine but while running only this error is coming. please help.

Comment: Would you mind to try `mix clean`? Or, even better, `rm -rf _build deps`, and rebuild everything from scratch.

Comment: Hey, I did everything, closed my vscode, removed all dependencies, removed _build then installing dependencies & started app but still it was same.

Comment: What version of `ranch` and `ranch_proxy_protocol` do you use? Check with `mix hex.outdated` or directly in `mix.lock`.

Comment: ranch             1.4.0
is says update not possible in mix hex.outdated.

Comment: That’s incorrect. Try to put the following line into your `mix.exs` (inside `deps` function): `{:ranch, "~> 1.7"}`.

Comment: it worked! thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating *Cowboy* to version *2*, make sure you have explicitly updated both `ranch` and `ranch_proxy_protocol` to modern versions. Usually putting the line

```
{:ranch, "~> 1.7"}
```

into `deps` section of your `mix.exs` file would resolve an issue.